# Broken interceptor detected - angular-loading-bar

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9, config

When I'm using IE9 I get this error:

"Broken interceptor detected: Config object not supplied in rejection:
 https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar/pull/50"

The all page just stuck on loading.
That's happens only on IE9 and under.

Thanks!

Comment: I also try to find a solution on the github link, but couldn't find something helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I use the https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar repo in a project.
That error means some of your requests are returning a 5XX error. check the console on your browser and add more info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify that valid JSON is being returned from the api, this type of error usually occurs when returned data from the api is not a valid JSON.
2. along with success callback, don't forget to use error callbacks as well no matter if you are 200% sure that you won't get any error, error callbacks help in exact identification of the error

Answer (score 0):

In the case I encountered, the request I sent to the server was an object that contained an array of objects, and it was complex and large, so it gave an error, and I corrected the object that I sent to the server in my request. And that's how I fix the error.
Be aware that what you send in your request may be a problem